# How to update cognito access token .net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito

I'm struggling with a problem of how to update the users Access/Id token on expiry I know how to get new tokens, i'm trying to work out how to update the users current/expired token once I have the updated ones? following code works fine and the response returns new access/id tokens, a null session (which is odd). I have tried GetUserReequest using the currrent access token then updating it, to no effect.  Documentation is a bit sparse on methods that expose access token also

```
 public async Task RefreshTokens(string token)
        {
            var request = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest
            {
                UserPoolId = userpool,
                ClientId = clientId,
                AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH,
                AuthParameters =
                {
                    {"REFRESH_TOKEN", token},
                    {"SECRET_HASH", secret}
                }
            };
            var response = await _cognitoIdentityProvider.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(request);

            //Do something here to update users tokens
        }
```

Comment: Well where is your token specified? It'll depend on that - are you returning the token?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary using open id and yes i am saving the token

Comment: Why are you saving a token? Are you not returning it some form of application requesting for it? Just return it

Comment: um i'm a little confused here, so you dont save any tokens, not the refresh or access then how to you even check if its expired? for example if i didnt save the access token, how would i get it to find the user in getuser ``` var rawAccessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);

Comment: What is this responsible for? Why are you getting a token?

Comment: the user will try to use the expired token, get a 401 and then attempt to get a new one through your endpoint

Comment: I've looked over oidc and can't see any examples that show how to refresh the access token, if you have any examples or pointers would be much appreciated as currently when the access token expires my users are still allowed to view the pages though they do get errors when trying to access claims.

Comment: Is `_cognitoIdentityProvider` your custom service or some of aws nuget package?

Comment: This task is part of a custom service,  using cognitoidentityprovider. I've pretty much given up ever solving this issue though